# Angular.js: Access JSON in HTTP Response Interceptor

Tags: json, angularjs, express

I am sending HTTP:

```
res.status(404).send({message: 'O Captain! My Captain!'});
```

I am intercepting HTTP in an Angular Service:

```
appServices.factory('ErrorInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', function($q, $injector) {
    var ErrorInterceptor = {
        responseError: function(response) {

            if (response.status == 404){

                console.log("[ErrorInterceptor] :" + response.status)      
                console.log("[ErrorInterceptor] :" + response.message)     
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
    return ErrorInterceptor;
}]);
```

Is only consoling-out the status `404`, but not the value of my JSON `message` member.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
console.log("[ErrorInterceptor] data.error:" + response.data.message)
```

#### Firebug

`O Captain! My Captain!`